# How to Work With Test Complete 10.60 with Safari

Tags: safari, testcomplete

I need to run my scripts on Safari Browser with test complete 10.60 please help.
I also have a licence for test complete 11

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: i have installed Safari on my machine but test complete does not recognize
is there any extension or patch for Safari browser

Answer (score 0):

Safari support [was dropped in TestComplete 10.40](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/76101/). So you need TestComplete 10.30 or earlier to record and run tests in Safari.